Confusion of d- and l- initials
In this video about the Palestinian territories, 小Lin pronounces 约旦 (i.e., the Jordan river), as yuelan. She does it twice in a row, in adjacent sentences, and then she does it inconsistently throughout the rest of the video, sometimes saying yuedan and other times yuelan. This implies to me that it's some kind of accent that occasionally peeks through and affects her otherwise very standard (Northern) speech. But on the other hand, I can't think of any other words I've heard her mix up D/L, although I was not previously on the look-out for them.
So, is there some dialect or accent that has a feature that would explain this? Is there something specific to 约旦 that causes this sort of mix-up? Or is this just a random idiosyncratic mistake with no further explanation?

I hear it as "d-" and wouldn't consider her accent substantially non-standard, but my listening is influenced by those dialects that DO have a historic /l/ > /d/ shift (parts of 闽南话), plus having high familiarity with the lexeme and context.

Believe me or not, I like 小Lin's program. But I do not quite agree with "her otherwise very standard (Northern) speech". Secondly, she speaks fast with humorous words to entertain the followers of her program.

@PdotWang perhaps "her otherwise very standard (Northern) accent"? She doesn't sound to me like she has an accent other than a generic northern one. I defer to your opinion on how non-standard her vocabulary choices are.

https://youtu.be/pJyMf5NCyV8?si=GRNn7DxQC9voOwN0

You can see that she is from DA LIAN, a northern city, which I know very well. people there don’t speak a dialect but they do have some local accent. I don’t put any negative comments on this topic.

By the way, many people don’t like the “very standard Chinese” like CCTV. Because they 一本正经地胡说八道。

旦在普通话中只有一种发音，不管它与谁组成词语，发音就是dàn，没有其他的发音，当然如果我错了请指出我的问题。
所有你听到其他的发音，只要发音不是dàn，就说明说话的这个人没有在说普通话，有可能是在说方言什么的，也有可能是发音不准等等其他一切的可能。这个原因可以了解，大概知道为什么没有发音为dàn即可，没有必要深究。如果非要深究，那就是按照普通话来说，她说错了(或她读错了)。

Are there 方言s that confuse d- and l- initials? Because otherwise this isn't really answering anything. I am well aware of the normatively correct pronunciation of the character, and I'm aware of the general concept of people's mandarin pronunciation being influenced by their local dialect. The question is about this specific person and why they did it.

@StumpyJoePete  如果不是说普通话，说方言的话，怎么说都可以，都不是错误的，因为说的是方言，每一个地方的方言都不一样，我也不知道视频中讲话的人是中国哪个省的人。如果你非得纠结 The question is about this specific person and why they did it. 我想这个答案只有视频中讲话那位人她最清楚，也只有她知道真正的原因。

@StumpyJoePete 首先最主要的问题，你还不能确定她说的那几个字是方言还是普通话(说的是普通话，但读错了)。通常情况下那个视频中的人应该说的是普通话。  关于"说的是普通话，但读错了"可以参考我们国家主席习近平在一些重要的公开场合还把一些字念(说或者读)错，这个原因是习主席确实说的是普通话，但他认为那个字就应该是他读错的那种读法。为什么他会认为那个字就应该是他读错的那种读法，很抱歉，这个原因我不能说太多，因为中国没有言论自由，很容易被警察请去喝茶，搞不好给个大的罪名： 诋毁国家主席 ，这样的事情在中国发生文革期间不是没有出现过。

Dialects have their own rules, it is not "怎么说都可以". If they had mixed up n- and l-, it would have been very reasonable to suggest they were Sichuanese or Nanjingese. And someone else managed to figure out where this person is from (大连) based on their internet presence. It's fine to read a question, realize you do not have any insight into the particular case being asked about, and leave the question unanswered. (Also, in the case of Xi Jinping, the mistakes were clearly not dialectical. There have been 多音字  where he chose wrong, and he's also misremembered literary expressions. Not a mystery.)
